# How do I allow mentors to remotely show powerpoint presentations without giving them direct access?

Tags: presentations

I have several mentors that go to clients and teach them skills. They use a bunch of powerpoint presentations that they show to the clients and then leave. The problem is, we've recently acquired external people that need access as well, but we want to deter them from copying the data. I say "deter", because I know it's impossible to "stop" them completely.

What is the easiest way to provide remote "viewing" access while exposing as little as possible of the information?

Comment: Hey Coderama, it all depends on your infrastructure. I mean you can have Terminal Servers that literally let them log in remotely and launch PowerPoint only. You could have Citrix Remote Apps which only gives them PowerPoint abilities. Place the Presentations to run within a browser window on a locked down website under IIS embedded in a website so they are unable to 'save' the file. Happy to assist further but need a bit more information as to what is feasible.

Comment: I'll update the ticket now, but I was hoping for the easiest way they could just open app, or even a browser, or some easy to open thing, and then login and just run the presentation. The only catch is, this thing running it, must not allow them to copy the files, just somehow run it through the app, or browser, or whatever.

Comment: Easiest way is to get an IIS website up and running (better to have it using SSL with a certificate). Have a login method really depending on your Website knowledge but you can use Domain authentication if they have login details on your AD. Create a page with a bunch of links to subfolders. Go to each presentation > File > Save as Web Page. Place each save in the subfolders in IIS so the HTML file is being ran when the link is clicked on the main page and volla! That should be all you need.

Comment: Of course considering things like port forwarding and static IP's. Also remembering that if someone has a lot of time and determination they can just Print Screen each slide. Possibly think about watermarking they pages?